# How to use narrator for reading the content of web pages?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8.1, narrator

How to read the content of **Web Pages** using **Narrator** in windows 8?

Tried using the commands specified below,

`Caps Lock + M` - Start reading

`Control + Caps Lock + I` - Read current paragraph

Both of the commands states that ***not an explorable content***, so is it possible to read content of web pages using narrator?

> EDIT
>
> It works well in Internet Explorer, what is the alternative solution
>   to make narrator work in Chrome?

Comment: Regarding your edit - Windows Narrator doesn't currently work with Google Chrome but a Narrator-like extension is available for Chrome, called "ChromeVox". Check it out here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Internet Explorer? I just pointed Narrator to a web page hosted in IE on a Windows 8.1 machine. I could do CapsLock+Y to move Narrator to the start of the text on the page, and then issue commands like CapsLock+I to read the next paragraph, or CapsLock+M to start reading the page.

Whether Narrator's text-related commands work as expected on pages is affected by whether the app presenting the text supports certain UI Automation "patterns". Patterns allow apps to programmatically describe the behavior of their UI. Narrator will leverage an app's Text pattern support to enable the user to move through the text in such ways a paragraph-by-paragraph, line-by-line, word-by-word or character-by-character. (More details on the UIA Text pattern are out at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2015/09/29/so-how-will-you-help-people-work-with-text-part-1-introduction.aspx.)

So I would expect Narrator to be able to interact with text in IE on a Win8.1 machine, but in other apps, it'll depend on whether they support the UIA Text pattern.

Thanks,

Guy